# How do I get a key in JSON when the path has a number in it

Tags: json, node.js

I'm using node js and I'm new to it and I'm trying to get JSON from the steam api, and it's working but I can't use the path because it has numbers in the first name.

https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=367520

That is the json I'm referencing and when I put `body.367520`I get an error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can access such object property using brackets `["key"]` where `key` is the number

```
var obj = {"367520":{"success":true}}
var key = obj["367520"]
```

Read more about accessing object properties [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)